# ApacheにVirtualHostでGitlabのページを表示するのが上手くいきません

Tags: centos, apache, nginx, gitlab

**実行環境:**
Apache 2.4.37
GitLab 15.11.0
CentOS

やりたいこと：ApacheとGitlab-ctlをStartして両方のトップページを表示したい。

Apacheにはポート80をListenしています。
このままGitlabをstartさせると競合するため、VirtualHostをhttpd設定ファイルに記述しており、Gitlabのeternal_urlにhttp://URL/gitlabと設定しています。

解釈ではApache→Nginx→gitlabとルーティングしてページを表示するイメージですが間違っているのかうまくいきません。

servernameはサーバーのIPアドレスにしており、VirtualHostで*:80　NginxでListen するのはApacheと同じポートにしています。そうするとGitlabのURLで503エラーになります。

質問の仕方が悪いなどはあると思いますし、あまりどこをどうすればいいのかわからないのでそのほかにも必要な情報があればご教示ください。
よろしくお願いします。

※追記VirtualHost(現状に編集5/8）

```
listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName [IPアドレス]
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  ProxyPass /gitlab http://localhost:8080/gitlab
  ProxyPassReverse /gitlab http://localhost:8080/gitlab

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/assets/
  RewriteRule .* - [L]

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyVia Off
  <Proxy *>
    Require all granted
  </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

nginxの記述

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name IPアドレス;

  location /gitlab {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:7000/gitlab;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

 location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

eternal_url
http://IPアドレス:7000/gitlab
```

Comment: Apacheの`VirtualHost`設定を追記することをおすすめします。(実現内容からするとProxy設定がどうなっているのかわかるようにすると良いと思います)

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます、追加しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apacheの`ProxyPass`(および`ProxyPassReverse`)の設定が、

```
http://IPアドレス:7000/gitlab
```

であれば、gitlabの`external_url`の設定は

```
http://IPアドレス:7000
```

かと思います。

＃机上調査のため試してはいません。
＃合わせて、gitlab(nginx)のListenポートも7000にする必要があると思います。

---

#### 訂正と追記

gitlabの構成を誤解しており、Proxyの転送先を誤っておりました。失礼しました。
次のようにすることで動作しないでしょうか?

1. Apacheとnginxの両方で、同一ポート(この場合`80`)でListenすることはできません。nginxの`Listen`を`8080`等、別ポートにする必要があります。
2. その上で、ApacheのProxy先をnginxにする必要があります。

例

```
  ProxyPass /gitlab http://IPアドレス:8080/gitlab
  ProxyPassReverse /gitlab http://IPアドレス:8080/gitlab
```

＃なお、以下の理解はあっていると思います。

> 解釈ではApache→Nginx→gitlabとルーティングしてページを表示するイメージですが

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。試してみましたがやはりうまくいきませんでした。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます、ご教示いただいたものを試してみたところ
PHPのindex.phpにはアクセス可能、GitLabは５０３になるという状態でした。
Gitlabのサービスが立ち上がっていない場合、404エラーになることから
Apache（成功）→Nginx（成功）→GitLab（失敗）という状態なのかもしれません。
自信はありませんが、少々試行錯誤して試してみます。

Comment: どうもGitlabに指定しているポートは外部からも接続できる必要があるようですね。レンタルしているサーバーに問い合わせてポートを開放しないとうまくいかないのかもしれません。